# How do I have this layout in Wordpress? It's a really simple issue, I'm just really not getting it

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

The sample website for the Responsive theme: http://themeid.com/demo/responsive/

I want to make a website like that with the Responsive theme. I've installed it on Wordpress and everything, but yet I don't know how to make anything other than simple blog posts. It's driving me mad.

I select "Full Width Page" as the template, and type in stuff, but I just get a basic page.
How do I make it so I have a main area, and then three boxes at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "three boxes at the bottom" are widgets.

Read the docs at themeid http://themeid.com/forum/topic/509/sidebar-widget-management/

and at wordpress.org http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets

Answer (score 0):

The functionality for the widget boxes may not be in the full width template..is there a template called something like homepage.if so you probably have to use that one..looks like the boxes are controlled on the widget page